# DirectX web installer license, distributable?

Tags: licensing, installation, directx

I want to bundle DirectX web installer with my application and run on user's system to update their DirectX. I want to know if redistribution of DirectX web installer is permitted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the License Agreement shown when launching the installer it seems that you cannot redistribute it. Then again, this didn't stop many setup developers.

A simple solution is to use a custom action which downloads and launches the installer. This way you use the Microsoft URL and meet the EULA requirements.